# How to start/call an Asp.net core app when i open CefSharp(winform) browser and close it on exit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cefsharp

Tools used: Visual Studio 2019, Asp.net core 5.0, CefSharp.WinForms v79.0

I have created an asp.net core app and a CefSharp browser.

If i click on the app.core and then on the browser it works fine.

I would like to some kind "automate" the whole process.

**How to start the Asp.net core app before the CefSharp fully loads/starts.**

**Can this be done from within the CefSharp browser,**

**so it opens the app.core in automatic and closes it too when CefSharp is closed?**

i can already do this by cmd-line :

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq APP.exe" |find ":" > nul

if errorlevel 1 taskkill /F /IM "APP.exe"

start C:\Server\APP.exe 

start C:\CEFSHARP\GUI.exe
```

Comment: It is possible to integrate asp.net core with CefSharp, requests can be made in memory, no separate process required. Using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chromium.AspNetCore.Bridge/1.0.1 There is an example at https://github.com/amaitland/Chromium.AspNetCore.Bridge/tree/master/CefSharp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Example.Wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start and stop process `"C:\Server\APP.exe"` from within `GUI.EXE` - this is assuming that you have a source code for `GUI.EXE`

You need to do the following in `GUI.EXE` source code (here I'm assuming that you are using Windows Forms application):

1. Add a [Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=net-5.0) event handler to your main form. From within your event handler you will need to start `"C:\Server\APP.exe"`. You can use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Server\APP.exe");` within event handler to start a process. Note that this method will return `Process` object which can be used to close the application.
2. Add a [Closing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing?view=net-5.0) event handler to your main form. From within your event handler you will need to stop `"C:\Server\APP.exe"` You can do this via [CloseMainWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?view=net-5.0) method of the Process object.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me:**

Form1.cs

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] processName = Process.GetProcessesByName("APP");
        if (processName.Length == 0)
        {
            Process myprocess = new Process();
            myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Server\\APP.exe";
            myprocess.Start();
        }
    }



        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("APP"))
        {
            p.Kill();
        }
    }
```